# INSERT IGNORE multiple rows; How to get resulting UNIQUE ID's

Tags: php, mysql

I have an event table, a tag table (fields: tag_id, tag), and an event_tag table (fields: event_id, tag_id). When a person creates a new event they can add tags which are added to the tag table via INSERT IGNORE (to make sure there are no duplicates).

Multiple tags can be added at once, and I then need to create corresponding records in the event_tag table.

The problem I need help with is how to get the resulting tag_id's after the INSERT IGNORE; sometimes new records will not be added because they already exist in the tag database, and therefore no id's will be returned.

Should I perform the INSERT IGNORE into the tag database, then perform a SELECT to get the corresponding tag_id's for the tags they added, and then perform another INSERT into the event_tag table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query (usually INSERT).  Will get the LAST entered one only (query), so if you use this method you will have to do the insert 1 value at a time. For multiple rows, gets the first generated `AUTO_INCREMENT` field from the insert query.

--edited for clarification, noticed after re-reading could be a little confusing--

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am aware of this, although it unfortunately doesn't help. I need a method of finding the 'tag_id' for each tag after the INSERT IGNORE; if the tag was already in the table no ID would be returned. I would also prefer to use one INSERT IGNORE for all tags rather than having a separate INSERT IGNORE for each tag.

Comment: Well you could loop through them, or the only other option I see is to perform a select on the same criteria after the `INSERT IGNORE` and see what values they were assigned.

Comment: I was thinking of doing a SELECT, but I wasn't sure if this would be considered the 'proper way'. I guess I'm looking for a second opinion regarding this method. Thanks for your input!

Comment: No problem.  Would be nice if they made it return some sort of associative array into the `mysql_insert_id`, but the issue with that I think would be what to call the indexes so you would know what the correlated to.